# DateTime.parse within Rails Scope

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm trying to convert a string to a time using DateTime.parse in a scope however, I'm getting an undefined local variable error.

Is it possible to convert a field within a scope or do I need to try something else?

My scope:

```
  scope :time_range, lambda {
    a = DateTime.parse(start_time_am)
    where("#{a} <= ?", Time.now.strftime('%H'))
  }
```

-- UPDATE --

Having played around with this, I've discovered I should probably overwrite the default accessor. I now have the following:

```
  def start_time_am
    read_attribute(:start_time_am).strftime("%H%M").to_i
  end
```

In the console, my start_time_am field now looks like:

```
 Promotion.last.start_time_am
  => 430
```

However, if I wanted to define a new field temporarily so I can still use the initial one.

I can access this in the console but not when searching. Eg.

```
   def start_time_new
     read_attribute(:start_time_am).strftime("%H%M").to_i
   end

  def self.time_range
    time = Time.now.strftime('%H%M').to_i
    where("start_time_new <= ?", time)
  end
```

Gives a unknown column error. I thought attr_reader would solve but it's not working.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you rewrite this as an equivalent method definition then it might be easier to figure out.

```
def self.time_range
  a = DateTime.parse(start_time_am)
  where("#{a} <= ?", Time.now.strftime('%H'))
end
```

Where is start_time_am coming from? The method doesn't have any arguments.

Comment: start_time_am is a field in the db. I'm thinking it would be easier to enter as datetime not string..

Comment: Can you give an example of records you expect this to return? Yes, start_time_am is a column in DB and it is defined as a method on model instances. But it is not defined on the class, what do you expect it to return otherwise?

Comment: Was just trying to convert the value so I can compare to Time.now

Answer (score 0):

In the end, I did the conversion in the where statement and got rid of the virtual attributes:

```
def self.time_available
  where("cast(start_time as time) <= cast(now() as time) and cast(end_time as time) >= cast(now() as time)")
end
```

Hope that helps someone

Comment: Virtual attributes are called "virtual" because they are not in the database. That is why you cannot use them in "where" clauses. However, I don't know why are you casting start_time and end_time, aren't they defined as `time` columns in DB schema?

Comment: By the way, you should click "Accept" on your answer if you consider the problem solved.

Comment: Cheers  for the virtual bit. Was driving me nuts but at least I understand now. Plus one for getting me going and I've accepted your answer. S